# How to configure nginx docker image to serve angular and allow page refresh?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have seen countless examples of people saying just paste

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /hockey/index.html =404;
    }
```

or

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
```

...or some other combination such as using $args etc, to get angular routes to load on page refresh. But none of these solutions are working for me.

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong? The page loads initally. Here's an example request from the console log:

```
"GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404
```

**Snippet from nginx.conf, literally only change is the added line:**

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /hockey/index.html =404;
    }
```

[snipped]

I have also omitted the /hockey and done a bunch of other things...

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine3.12 AS builder
COPY . ./hockey
WORKDIR /hockey
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@10.0.0
RUN ng build --aot=false --prod --build-optimizer=false --base-href=/

FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=builder /hockey/dist/hockey/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If anyone has any idea what combination I need (is my base-href correct etc?) please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like

```
location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```